# google map editable/draggable polygons

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I am trying to find out how to edit *polygon* by dragging its vertices. There are **draggable/editable** properties for polygon in the `JavaScript API`.

But how can I implement same functionality for `android API`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this. I add markers for each vertex, save it to list and add onDragListener.  Every time when onMarkerDrag callback occurs, i get latLng from markers and set them to polygon.

```
 @Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    if (mPolygon == null) {
        return;
    }
    mPolygon.setPoints(markersToLatLng(mVertexMarkers));
}

private List<LatLng> markersToLatLng(List<Marker> markers) {
    List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (markers == null) {
        return latLngs;
    }
    for (Marker m : markers) {
        latLngs.add(m.getPosition());
    }
    return latLngs;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527262/how-to-make-polygon-editable-on-google-map#comment108921913_61527262 please see this question. i also have the same problem i use this code